# Setting Email Headers (Return-Path, Sender, Message ID) in .Net Application

Tags: .net, email, header, smtp, return-path

We are creating an application in .Net and are currently on the final stages and need to inject an email message through SMTP while setting a variety of options in the 'email headers'.

The three values we are focused on are:

Return-Path

Sender

Message-ID

Currently in our code we have this:

```
BodyMessage.Sender = new MailAddress(bounce_address);
```

(Where the 'bounce_address' is the address we we want the bounces to go to.)

This code seems to set both the **Return-Path** and **Sender**.

However, we want those values to be *different*.

Is there a value we can use so that when we send the message we can specify the return-path to be one thing and the sender to be another?

We tried this, but it does not work:

```
BodyMessage.Headers.Add("Sender", "1234567@example.com");
```

That code just gets completely ignored.

Any ideas?

For the message-ID we have tried this:

```
BodyMessage.Headers.Add("Message-ID", "abcdefgh@sample.com");
```

But, that also gets ignored.

If, however, we specify a custom header value such as "X-Message-ID" then this code works:

```
BodyMessage.Headers.Add("X-Message-ID", "abcdefgh@sample.com");
```

But, that is not what we want since we don't want to add an additional email-header item, but rather supply the main message-id header element.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you have a solution for this? I am looking for a way to set the "return-path" to a different address.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into problems like that (before they introduced ReplyTo collection, it used to be a single item only), I ended up using a 3rd-party SMTP library and stopped using the .NET library altogether. I found out that basically, there's no way to override the default behavior - they specifically prohibit you from settings those headers yourself. (for some reason that I'm failing to grasp)

[DnSmtp](http://dnsmtp.codeplex.com/)

As the author of that library admits, it's rough on the edges here and there, I had to polish it myself before using it. But I was successful in the end.

PS. You can use any .NET email library, not necessarily DnSmtp. Or you could write your own SMTP client (a bit tedious, but possible).

Comment: Thanks for the super quick reply, Mr. TA. Your help is very much appreciated. And, at least now we know we weren't just missing something obvious within the default .NET library.

Comment: That DnSmtp library does appear to be a bit dated.... are there others you would recommend (since you seem to know the landscape of this issue really well)? I don't think we'd want to write our own library. Thanks again!

Comment: Not really, sorry. It was dated already when I had to use it 2-3 years ago :) There's very little demand for a library like that, hence the lack of innovation in the "alt.net" sphere when it comes to SMTP clients (the .NET one works for **most** people). Check Codeplex and Google Code and other sites like that before giving up. If you can't find anything else, try DnSmtp... it may work for you w/o changing it (we had to send a bunch of non-English characters which wasn't supported, your requirements may be different).